# Is it possible to override the Subversion HTML pages?

Tags: php, html, svn, webdav, mod-dav-svn

I have a subversion server, providing subversion access via Apache2 and mod_dav_svn

The system works fine and clients can access the repositories with SVN client such as TortoiseSVN etc.

Users can also access HTML renderings of the same URLs.

Can these renderings be over-ridden, or replaced?  If so, how would i go about it?

Comment: I think your question should have been ...
Is it possible to override mod_dav_svn pages?

... because subversion does not provide HTML interface. It is the client proxy mod_dav_svn that does it.

Comment: you're absolutely right, i have since found a couple of XSLT examples which render the output within the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by adding a `SVNIndexXSLT` directive in the `<Location>` of your repository in the `httpd.conf`:

```
<Location: /repository>
DAV svn
SVNPath /var/repository
SVNIndexXSLT "/svnstyle.xsl"
[...]
</Location>
```

With this directive, Subversion will generate an xml directory listing, instead of an html one, and you can style this xml listing any way you want in the specified xslt file.
Remember that the path you specify in the `SVNIndexXSLT` directive is an url of your webserver, the browser must have access to it to render the pages correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `xslt` to configure the output. I.e see [http://www.reposstyle.com](http://www.reposstyle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a different way of viewing your subversion repository via a web interface, I'd suggest looking into Trac (http://trac.edgewall.com).  You can even view Trac's own Subversion repository at http://trac.edgewall.org/browser.

I'm not sure if it's possible to skin the Subversion browser itself without digging into the Trac code, but the overall Trac look and feel can certainly be modified, as was done by the Maia Mailguard project at http://maiamailguard.com/maia/browser.

Comment: Trac's pages can be skinned, even though I found it to be a bit of a pain in the arse to do because of the template language they use, Geshi.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to skin default repository browser but maybe [Warehouse](http://warehouseapp.com/) can help you?